# AWS SSO using Azure Active Directory and AWS IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, aws-iam, active-directory

I'm trying to create a flow where users can be authenticated to AWS Console using Aure Active Directory Credentials, and the access of their accounts can be managed using IAM.

I have connected AWS SSO with Azure Active Directory, but I'm not able to configure AWS SSO as the identity provider of AWS IAM. Also when I'm trying to login to AWS Console as the user who has been assigned to the application, AWS url is opening and showing a message

`You do not have any applications`

Can anyone please help me to understand, what can be the issue/step that I'm missing while setting up SSO?

Steps performed:

1. In the AWS Console of root user, I've choosen `External Provider` as SSO identity provider, and downloaded the `AWS SSO SAML metadata` xml file.
2. In Azure, I've added an enterprise application `AWS Single Sign-on`
3. In `AWS Single Sign-on` application, I've choosen `SAML` as the option for `Single sign-on`, and uploaded `AWS SSO SAML metadata` xml file, and set the `Sign on URL`.
4. I have downloaded the  `Federation Metadata XML` file from Azure, and uploaded it to AWS `IdP SAML Metadata`. This completes my setup for SSO.
5. For auto-provisioning, In AWS, I've changed `Provisioning` from Manual to Automatic. So, AWS provided me with `SCIM endpoint` and `Secret Token`.
6. In `AWS Single Sign-on` application on Azure, I went to `Provisioning` and entered `SCIM endpoint` and `Secret Token`. Now the provisioning started and it is giving a message that it will sync every 40 minutes.
7. I've assigned a user(say B.Simon) access to the `AWS Single Sign-on` application.
8. Now,`Provisioning` is completed and the root account of AWS is showing the user(B.Simon).

Issues:

1. When trying to login with the user credentials(B.Simon), awsapps page is giving a message that "You do not have any applications".
2. From the root account of AWS, I'm not able to create the IAM role to provide restricted access to B.Simon